# Installing Python into user-accessible build folder during build process

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, build

Trying to install python inside my build folder in CMake.  At heart though it doesnt seem to work as documented for a few versions I have tried.

```
.\python-3.10.7-amd64.exe /quiet /log C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\python_install.log TargetDir="C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\PythonTest"
```

I get a UAC dialog as if the installer is going to do something that requires admin and I proceed with that, but it doesn't install anything. I get a 60KB logfile that does have some errors I cant make out:

```
[0BC4:2E38][2023-04-27T11:15:22]e000: Error 0x80070002: Process returned error: 0x2
[0BC4:2E38][2023-04-27T11:15:22]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed to execute EXE package.
[0AC4:1860][2023-04-27T11:15:22]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[0AC4:1860][2023-04-27T11:15:22]w350: Applied non-vital package: compileall_AllUsers, encountered error: 0x80070002. Continuing...
[0BC4:2E38][2023-04-27T11:15:22]i301: Applying execute package: compileallO_AllUsers, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\F542DE6E7D2F50806ADFFD8B7A5ADE6D8DA3DF66\py.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\F542DE6E7D2F50806ADFFD8B7A5ADE6D8DA3DF66\py.exe" -3.10 -O -E -s -Wi "C:\Users\kalen\Documents\PythonTest\Lib\compileall.py" -f -x "bad_coding|badsyntax|site-packages|py2_|lib2to3\\tests|venv\\scripts" "C:\Users\kalen\Documents\PythonTest\Lib"'
[0BC4:2E38][2023-04-27T11:15:22]e000: Error 0x80070002: Process returned error
```

Using a guide here:
https://silentinstallhq.com/python-3-10-silent-install-how-to-guide/

I want to do this in CMake and am doing that as well and have code for it, but at core this process just doesn't work as advertised so far?  I am now in the process of trying more versions.  There are some .msi based ones in older versions which have different argument structure but similar functionality.

My goal here is to run python straight from cmake build folder and bypass need to use dockers and things of that nature.

Answer (score 0):

I went with python-3.6.3-amd64 and it actually worked.  Not sure where the problem starts but I can do some more research here if anyones curious.  Also you dont get the UAC dialog with 3.6.3, the default method is to not install for all users so just /quiet and TargetDir="AbsPath" is needed